# Выборка из большой базы MySQL по 200 записей за раз - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день. Не могу найти ни одного примера такой выборки. Хотелось бы ознакомиться с best practice, перед тем как писать велосипед

В коде php нужно обращаться к базе, последовательно выбирая все строки, причем не более 200 за раз

Может быть кто-то сталкивался?

Comment: использовать limit и offset?

Comment: Не сталкивался с offset, спасибо за подсказку

Получается будет что-то вроде этого: http://www.tigir.com/paging.htm
Только в цикле. Верно?

Comment: @silent-box - верно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/*x - номер страницы*/
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 200,($x-1)*200
```